# What happens when a null collection is queried with LINQ query syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, null

My understanding is nothing will happen.

For instance this code:

```
foreach (var some in (from u in possiblyNullCollection ) ) 
{
    // 
}
```

Should be guarded as:

```
if ( possiblyNullCollection != null ) 
{ 
    foreach (var some in (from u in possiblyNullCollection ) ) 
    {
     // 
    }
}
```

Or is it safe to query a null collection?

Comment: ...Have you tried it?

Comment: Takes like 1 minute to try this out

Comment: Related to... [Why does .NET foreach loop throw NullRefException when collection is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088147/why-does-net-foreach-loop-throw-nullrefexception-when-collection-is-null)

Comment: ... or a minute to research the many resources online that complain when it doesn't work. [Also related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644715/c-sharp-code-simplification-query-the-null-container-and-the-foreach-loop)

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455311/is-ifitems-null-superfluous-before-foreacht-item-in-items) is likely a duplicate (this should probably be a faq...)

Comment: I don't get why the downvotes, after all this is a legit question. If it is so trivial a simple < 1m answer would do.

Comment: Anyway, I've got my answer and I voted to have it closed.

Comment: @OscarRyz: It's not a legit question because it would've taken less time to try it yourself than it took for you to post the question. A good stackoverflow question is well defined, and presents what has already been tried and why those things didn't solve the problem. Nothing personal, but this type of question comes across as "Hey, I don't feel like trying this. Could someone do it for me." Note that the issue itself is a valid one. Many people feel that these functions should not throw an exception in these cases. But the answer about if they do or not is right in front of you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A null collection will throw an exception if you query it with LINQ. You need to check for null.

Empty collections are fine however.

Something to keep in mind is that it's generally considered bad practice for collections to be null. Similar to having null items in a collection, it can cause a lot of bugs.

[image: LINQPad Window showing the results of the query]

Comment: What's the common idiom to handle this? To check it as in my second sample?

Comment: Usually the best way to handle it is to not allow the collection to be null to begin with. 

If it's a class field, initialize it to an empty collection. 
If it's a method parameter, check it for null at the beginning of the method, and throw an ArgumentNullException if it is. 

Assuming you have to deal with null collections for whatever reason, you can wrap the foreach in an if block like you did, or you can use the null coalesce operator in the foreach block like this `foreach (var some in (from u in (possiblyNullCollection ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>())))` where T is the type of the item.